# How to set permanent IP address for Zebra Printer using ZPL?

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I am trying to change wired network settings of Zebra Printer ZD621 by ^NS command. My code looks like this:

```
^XA
^NSp,192.168.15.51,255.255.255.0,192.168.15.1
^XZ
```

It doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you reboot the printer after? also I do not remember if that command requires a ^JUS after the ^NS to save it...

Comment: @banno, thank you, yes I did it by ~JR, also I tried ^JUS and still nothing. Probably problem is in ~JR command, but I also tried restart physically it didn't help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

! U1 setvar "internal_wired.ip.protocol" "permanent"

! U1 setvar "internal_wired.ip.addr" "192.168.15.51"

! U1 setvar "internal_wired.ip.gateway" "192.168.15.1"

! U1 setvar "internal_wired.ip.netmask" "255.255.255.0"

! U1 setvar "device.reset" ""

make sure all of these commands start on a new line and the device.reset is floowed by a new line.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
^XA
^ND2,P,192.168.15.51,255.255.255.0,192.168.15.1
^NBC
^NC1
^NPP
^XZ
^XA
^JUS
^XZ
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).